# Element's Click Intercepted

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

i've been trying to make selenium click a button for me but all i get is element click intercepted

i first thought about exception handling but i want to know if there's a better way

eitherway i am a bit confused

````py
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from win10toast import ToastNotifier as Notifier
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

Path: str = "C:\\Users\\rolan\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe"
Link: str = "https://www.roblox.com"

Notification = Notifier()
Notification.show_toast("hulks bot", "settings things up...")

sleep(1)

Option = Options()
Option.add_argument("start-maximized")

Browser = webdriver.Chrome(service = Service(Path), options = Option)
Browser.get(Link)

def Perform_Actions():
    sleep(1)

    Login_Button = Browser.find_element(By.ID, "main-login-button")
    Login_Button.click()

Perform_Actions()```

much appreciated help
````

Answer (score 0):

fixed all you needed to do was just click on the main container of everything(just the screen)